# Images don't get smaller

Tags: jquery

I have a table and each image is in a div inside a table cell. As there were many images with different sizes I wrote the following code to make them smaller if their height was biggher than 200px and else if their width was bigger than 118px but this script is not working properly, sometimes it works when I refresh my page. What am i doing wrong?

```
var tableImages = $("table td>div> img");
        tableImages.each(function () {
            var curTableImgHeight = $(this).height();
            var curTableImgWidth = $(this).width();

            if (curTableImgHeight > 200) {
                $(this).css({ "max-width": "188px", "height": "100%" });
            }
            else if (curTableImgWidth > 188) {
                $(this).css({ "max-height": "200px", "width": "100%" });

                var parDivHeight = $(this).parent().height();
                var topmargin = (parDivHeight - $(this).height()) / 2;
                $(this).css('margin-top', topmargin);
            }


        });
```

Comment: Sounds like you are checking imge size before it is loaded

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to use `$( window ).load()` :

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    var tableImages = $("table > td > div > img");
    ....
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: DOM can be ready before image has been loaded, giving not accurate image size

Comment: @A.Wolff actually that is the problem. The OP stated that the script works on refresh - that is because all the images are in the cache giving correct sizes on DOM ready. Optionally one could explicitly state the image sizes in the document beforehand (=server side) so that you can use domready instead.

Comment: Ya, using window `onload` handler is the easiest way to solve OP's issue, i guess

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use jQuery here.

```
.img {
    max-width:188px;
    max-height:200px;

    /* set min width and height if needed */
}
```

Simple and clean

If you have all images different size you won't get them to look exactly same. You have to choose your layout width or height and say that all images have to match that width...

Comment: Defining both, height and width 100% will distort the images when the proportions don't match but otherwise it's a good solution.

Comment: OR unfortunately won't work either, (in the case that there are images in both portrait AND landscape mode) because this may cause the image to disrespect the size of the container. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4SvY6/)